# How to update from eclipse oxygen to photon while also getting Java in?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

I first used to program in Java on BlueJ. But BlueJ was lightweight so I switched to IntelliJ IDEA. I am quite a beginner so I started to learn C++. So, I downloaded Eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers(Oxygen). Now IntelliJ has a lot slow startup time and so I want to program in Java in the Eclipse IDE and I also want to update it to Photon. And I still want my C++ running on that. Is there a way to do both of these things?

Comment: Eclipse is a platform. Install Eclipse Photon and then "Help > Install New Software, Pick the Photon Release URL" and select whatever languages you like.

Comment: There are two possible approaches: [1] See [Upgrading existing Eclipse IDE and Installed Features to newer release](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Upgrading_existing_Eclipse_IDE_and_Installed_Features_to_newer_release), to upgrade your existing Oxygen installation. [2] An alternative approach is to do a fresh install of Photon which can co-exist with your existing Oxygen installation. See [Fresh install](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Fresh_install) for details on that.

Answer (score 0):

step to update :
1. open eclipse 
2. click on help
3. check update
4. update now

download:https://www.eclipse.org/photon/